# Update statement with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, executenonquery

Simple question, is it possible to achieve this query this with Entity Framework when updating one entity?

```
update test set value = value + 1 where id = 10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really under this form no.

You will have to select all entities that match your criteria, foreach over them and update them.

If you are looking for something that will do it right in the DB because your set could be huge, you will have to use SQL directly. (I don't remember if EF has a way to execute UPDATE queries directly the way Linq To SQL does).

Comment: Just what i suspected, i'll use a sproc

Comment: Or you might be able to use this: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Use the Batch Update feature of the [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended), like this:

```
dbContext.Tests.Update(t => t.Id == 10, t => new Test() { Value = t.Value + 1 });
```

Comment: MutantNinjaCodeMonkey mentioned this library in a comment on a different answer. I found the library fit the bill so well that it was worth calling attention to in its own separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

It should be, it will just be a little bit more constrained generally.

```
var myEntity = context.First(item => item.id == 10);
myEntity.value += 1;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Should produce similar SQL, you can watch the profiler to see what SQL is actually being generated, but it should be very similar to your statement.

Comment: The EF-generated SQL is quite different: two SQL statements, which are not atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Since Entity Framework Core 7 you can do this:

```cs
await context.Tests.Where(c => c.Id == 10).ExecuteUpdateAsync(
    s => s.SetProperty(b => b.Value, b => b.Value + 1));
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples